# React & React-Native versions conflict while installing material-ui

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I'm trying to install material-ui on new React-Native project which running **react-native: 0.26.2** & **react: "15.0.2**.
when I've installed material-ui npm package I've gotten these errors & warnings:

```
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency react@^15.1.0 included from react-addons-update will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency react@^15.1.0 included from react-addons-transition-group will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency react@^15.1.0 included from react-addons-create-fragment will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "material-ui"
npm ERR! node v4.2.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.0.2 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-native@0.26.2 wants react@15.0.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@15.1.0 wants react@^15.1.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-tap-event-plugin@1.0.0 wants react@^15.0.0-0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer material-ui@0.15.0 wants react@^15.0.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Ali/Desktop/app/second/npm-debug.log
```

It seems there is version conflict for using last version of materil-ui with last react-native build.

Is there anyone that realize what can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same error with a React Native project that I initialised with `react-native init AwesomeProject`.

I edited the `package.json` file so that an older version of react is being used, fixing the version conflict.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.26.2",
    "react-native-material-design": "^0.3.6"
  }
}
```

You may need to delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again.